# Indenting Texts to the left and right on the same line

Tags: indentation

I need help on this. I am making a template for our assignment. On the top page, the first line contains Name placed on the left and Subject on the right. Second line contains Date placed on the left and Assignment No. on the right. How do I do this? Thanks..

Comment: `\noindet{}Name: foo\hfill{}Subject: bla`

Comment: There is a typo: it should be `\noindent`. Note that *Subject* and *Assignment* will not be aligned on the left, but the answers below will do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo
\usepackage{textcomp}   %% provides fancy \textnumero
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Name: & \\
Date: &
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Subject: & \\
Assignment \textnumero: &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out by egreg, you can also use a single `tabular*` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}%% just for demo
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
Name: & Subject: \\
Date: & Assignment \textnumero:
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd do it with a single `tabular*`

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't specify what TeX format are you using, I write the format-independent answer (as usually) based only on TeX primitives. Note, that you needn't use any `\halign`, i.e. any table environment.

Because you didn't specify if the form is blank or filled, I suggest both variants: `\emptyheader` and `\header`. The first one does left alignment of the words "Subject" and "Assignment" as in the another answers here.

```
\def\header#1#2#3#4{%
   \hbox to\hsize{Name: #1\hfil Subject: #2}
   \hbox to\hsize{Date: #3\hfil Assignment No: #4}
}
\def\emtyheader{%
   \hbox to\hsize{\vbox{\hbox{Name:}\hbox{Date:}}\hfil
                  \vbox{\hbox{Subject:}\hbox{Assignment No:}}\kern2em}
}
% try this:

\emtyheader  % empty form

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\header{Pepa}{Problem}{01.01.2015}{1}  % filled form
```